# Как подменить URL?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Как переписать URL без редиректа?
т.е. юзер заходит на `site.ru/catalog/`, переписываем ему строку в браузере на `site.ru/irk/catalog/`, но отображаем `site.ru/catalog/`?
`irk` в htaccess получаю из `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} CITY=([^;]+) [NC]`
Ниже то что пробовал в htaccess, но сейчас по адресу `site.ru/irk/catalog/` открывается эта страница, а не `site.ru/catalog/`

```apache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (^.)+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/irk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} CITY=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Редирект на каталог с городом, если нет в запросе ключа noredirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*noredirect.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} CITY=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L,R=302]

# По обращению на каталог города проксируем запрос на основной каталог с запретом редиректа
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\/]+/catalog(.*)
RewriteRule .+ /catalog%1?noredirect [L,QSA]
```